# Do operating systems implement techniques to ask programs to give up non-vital memory in times of shortages?

Tags: memory, operating-systems, memory-usage

When a system is running low on available memory can it ask programs in general to give up any non-vital memory without shutting down. 
Like a process signal which causes the processes to yield any memory they can which does not render them unusable.

Think of it as a stage before caching them to disk or terminating them altogether.

Any Operating systems that do this?

Comment: BTW: there are just *so many* Operating Systems (or Programming Languages or Virtual Machines or Libraries or …) that the question "is there any OS that does this" is pretty meaningless, since the answer is almost always going to be "Yes". Among the tens of thousands of OSs, you can be pretty sure that *everything* which is possible or thinkable *has* been done, just by pure statistics.

Comment: Windows has a "high memory" event.

Answer (score 2):

iOS does. First, it will ask apps to give up memory when it gets tight (and apps that give up memory when needed tend to live longer), and there is a class (I think) NSCache which contains cached objects that can disappear any time. MacOS 9 did similar things. On MacOS X the assumption is that there is unlimited memory.

Comment: Linux and Android do it too (In different ways. Android uses a custom Out of Memory killer). Feel free to look it up and add it to your answer.

Comment: @RubberDuck Android straight up Kills process when Out of memory , I'm asking about giving a signal of sorts to allow applications to release some memory on their own

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `gnasher729`'s answer, iOS also has 
a delegate method on [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) called [`didReceiveMemoryWarning()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621409-didreceivememorywarning).

> #### Discussion
>
> Your app never calls this method directly. Instead, this method is
>   called when the system determines that the amount of available memory
>   is low.
>
> You can override this method to release any additional memory used by
>   your view controller. If you do, your implementation of this method
>   must call the super implementation at some point.

Unfortunately, 99% of the implementations I've seen are this default stub:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

It's a bit of a [tragedy of the commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) scenario. Every app would benefit from implementing this behavior correctly (due to a lower chance of being force-stopped or paged to storage), but each app individually benefits from not implementing it (snappier response time, due to not needing to recompute/reload purged resources).